# Preferred way to set up a JSF start page?

Tags: java, deployment, jsf, facelets, web.xml

I'm using JSF 2.0 to build a website. Eclipse generated the following web.xml file

```
...
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
...
```

So to view my application i have to visit "localhost/myApp/**faces**/index.xhtml". I would prefer to view it directly by visiting "localhost/myApp/index.xhtml"

I see two options for this:

Changing the web.xml to the following

```
...
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
...
```

Or setting up an index.xhtml in my base dir that does a javascript/meta direct to faces/index.xhtml.

Which do you think is better ? Or is there another way how you would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't map the `FacesServlet` on *all* requests. You don't want to get static (non-JSF) requests go through the whole JSF lifecycle. It'll only add unnecessary overhead. Rather map the `FacesServlet` on an `url-pattern` of `*.xhtml`.

If you have another `xhtml` files as well which doesn't need to go through the JSF factory, then rather choose a different `url-pattern`, like the commonly used `*.jsf`. You don't need to rename the *actual* file extension, the `FacesServlet` will automagically locate the right resource.

*Definitely* do not use a JS/meta redirect for the home page. Just declare it as `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`.

---

That said, when having the latest version and properly configured, Eclipse should by default autogenerate the `web.xml` with the `FacesServlet` mapped on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsf`. Ensure that you're using the latest version (Helios) and doing everything right in Eclipse (configure project facets).

Comment: Hi,

that was also the option I thought about (mapping only .xhtml). I use Eclipse Helios and it generates .xhtml files as default and also the above web.xml with the servletmapping of /faces/..
I thought .jsf is not recommend anymore in JSF 2.0 ? I only have dynamic pages (because of i18n) so mapping every .xhtml should be ok

Comment: Ah, that must be then my specific Eclipse configuration. The only which is not recommended anymore in JSF 2.0 is using JSP instead of Facelets :)